# How to automatically check if two commands output the same number?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

Say I have two grep commands:

```
grep -rno 'foo' --include \*.txt|wc -l
grep -rno 'bar' --include \*.txt|wc -l
```

How would I automatically check that their output is the same number, and print "yes" or "no" accordingly? I guess I may need a script to do this, but perhaps not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bsh
test "$(grep -rno 'foo' --include \*.txt|wc -l)" = "$(grep -rno 'bar' --include \*.txt|wc -l)" && echo Yes || echo No
```

or

```bsh
var1=$(grep -rno 'foo' --include \*.txt|wc -l)
var2=$(grep -rno 'bar' --include \*.txt|wc -l)
test "$var1" = "$var2" && echo Yes || echo No
```

Under shell everything you run may become a script. Whether you make it a script or not depends on how complex it is and how often you want to run it.